# What does => (equals greater than) mean in Fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, variable-assignment, fortran90

I'm looking through some old Fortran 90 code and have come across the `=>` symbol:

```
var => item
```

It looks like it's being used for some sort of assignment.

Searching Google for *"arrow symbol Fortran"* or *"equals greater than symbol Fortran"* gives me no related material.

Comment: I couldn't believe how hard it was to find basic information on this operator without explicitly knowing it's name (especially for a language that's been around so long). Hopefully this Q&A will rectify that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surprisingly, searching *"equals arrow symbol Fortran"* yields some results.

**"=>"** is commonly referred to as the [**pointer assignment operator**](http://www.adt.unipd.it/corsi/Bianco/www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_12.html).
(Though it is not [truly an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887568/3745896) as it returns no value.)

It is used to **associate a chosen reference name with a target:**

```
reference => target
```

The above can be read as "reference *refers to* target"

Most often this reference occurs in the form of a [pointer](http://math.scu.edu/~dsmolars/ma60/notesforpnt.html). In this case you could say "reference *points to* target". This is a helpful way to remember what this operator does as its literal appearance is of an arrow pointing from reference to target.

**Further Uses**
Additional uses including making local aliases for various items such as module components, procedures, and even arbitrary expressions. For a full explanation of all of these uses see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887568/3745896).

**Pointer assignment vs. Traditional Assignment (=)**
Here's a quick example from the above link that illustrates how pointer assignment differs from classic assignment (**"="**). Basically this shows that once a target has been established, the pointer is treated *as that target* for basic statements.

```
pt => x ! pt points to x

y = pt ! y equals x

pt => y ! pt points to y

pt = 17 ! y equals 17
```

Other Resources:
[General documentation on Fortran pointers](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/lectures/42.html)

Answer (score 31):

`=>` appears in six contexts as a syntactic element in modern Fortran, many, but not all, related to pointers: *pointer assignment*; *pointer initialization*; *procedure (pointer) declaration*; *type-bound procedure declaration*; *association*; *renaming*.  There is close connection between most of these.  Loosely, in many `=>` can be viewed as providing an alternative temporary or permanent means of referencing another entity.   In none, however, is `=>` acting as an operator.<sup>1</sup>

### Pointer assignment

Pointer assignment is one of the traditional appearances of `=>`, appearing in Fortran 90.  It is used to associate a pointer with a target, and is explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885867).

### Use association renaming

Renaming of entities use associated involves the element `=>` and is the other appearance in Fortran 90/95 code.  Such `use` statements are like

```
use mod_a, c=>a
use mod_b, only : cc => bb
```

Following such a `use` statement the module entities `a` and `bb` are known by the local names `c` and `cc`.

### Pointer initialization

Pointer initialization is much like pointer assignment where `=>` appears.  Pointer initialization defines the initial pointer association of the pointer.  We see this in statements such as

```
real, target :: a
real, pointer :: b=>a
real, pointer :: c=>NULL()
```

With this explicit initializtion, the pointer `b` here is initially associated with `a` and the pointer `c` is initially unassociated.  These two forms are helpful in modern Fortran in that in Fortran 90 a pointer always starts life initially of undefined association status.  Here we know that `b` and `c` have defined pointer association status, and we can use `ASSOCIATED`.

For derived type components such syntax gives default initialization.

### Procedure declaration

Much as with explicit/default initialization for data objects `=>` features in defining the initial association of a procedure pointer.

```
procedure(proc_interface), pointer :: proc1 => donkey
procedure(proc_interface), pointer :: proc2 => null()
```

Here, `proc1` is again initially associated with the procedure `donkey` and we can have such things as

```
call proc1(...)
```

much as we could when `proc1` is pointer assigned with `donkey` outside the declaration statement.  `proc2` is, as expected, initially not associated.

As with data object components of derived types `=>` can feature in setting the initial association of a derived type's procedure pointer component:

```
type a
  procedure(proc_interface), pointer :: proc => donkey
end type a
```

### Type-bound procedure declaration

Conceptually related to the above is the use of `=>` in declaring type-bound procedures.

```
type a
 contains
  procedure :: proc => donkey
  generic :: assignment(=) => type_a_eq
end type a
```

Here in the type `a` `proc` is a binding name so that `b%proc` (for `b` an entity of type `a`) is a procedure reference.  We also, through `type_a_eq`, have defined assignment with entities of type `a` on the left-hand side.

### Association

`=>` appears in four association contexts.  The `associate`, `change team`, `select type` and `select rank` constructs associate a name with a selector.

From Fortran 2003 we have

```
associate (a => 1+2)
  ... ! In this block we have an entity named a
end associate
```

and

```
class(*) b   ! b is unlimited polymorphic
select type (a => b)
  type is (real)
    ... ! a is a non-polymorphic real here
end select
```

Introduced in Fortran 2018 we have

```
dimension(..) b  ! b is assumed rank
select rank (a => b)
  rank (1)
    ... ! a is a rank-1 array here
end select
```

and

```
change team (team_value, a[*] => b)
... ! In this block we have a coarray named a
end team
```

These associations differ from pointers.  `a` in the `associate` block needn't be (and in the example above isn't) a variable.

---

<sup>[1]  The concept of *operator* is precisely defined in the Fortran language, such as in 3.2.4 of the Fortran 2008 specification.  Unlike many other languages, assignment (with `=`) itself is not an operation, but a statement.  In C-like languages we can have `(a=b)` as an expression returning a result: this is not the case in Fortran.  The same holds for pointer assignment in Fortran.  The other cases above are wholly distinct from this idea of assignment.  In Fortran, even `=` appearing in initialization is not the same thing as assignment.  `=>` cannot be viewed as having one effect.</sup>