# what's the meaning of "iostat" argument in open statement?

Tags: fortran

I am confused by the use of the 'iostat' argument in open file. As it's said, when the open command succeeds, the 'iostat' gets a value of 0.

```
open(unit=99, file='vel_zcor22.txt', status='old', iostat=ierr, err=100)
100 if(ierr .ne. 0) then
    print*, 'open file error'
endif   
print*, ierr
```

Why is not the 'iostat' used to tell the state rather than the 'ierr'. As my understanding of assignment operator, the 'ierr' transfers its value to 'iostat'. So what is the role of the 'ierr' playing in this procedure?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation/tutorial (etc) which tells you about `iostat` and `ierr`?  As you have it, you're confused about something but it isn't easy for us to say what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `open` statement, the `iostat=ierr` is using `iostat=` as a *specifier*.  It is not an assignment, transferring the value of `ierr` to the variable `iostat`.

Much like when using keywords in a subroutine or function reference (where `call sub(a=x)` associates the actual argument `x` with the dummy argument `a`), what is happening is more:

> use the variable `ierr` to store the resulting status of the statement.

So, when "`iostat` gets a value of 0" what really happens is the variable `ierr` becomes defined.

You could instead use any variable name instead of `ierr`, and typically one often uses `iostat`:

```
open(..., iostat=iostat, ...)
```

Equally, the other parts you see aren't assignments either.  That is:

```
open(unit=99, file='vel_zcor22.txt', status='old', iostat=ierr, err=100)
```

may look like assignments, but it's still saying:

> open on unit 99, this file, with status `'old'`, passing control to statement labelled `100` if there's an error.

It isn't setting a variable `unit` to 99, etc.

Comment: But here is open a function? For a function, the formal parameters are assigned by real parameters when called.

Comment: `open` isn't a function, it's a statement.

Comment: Reference from the standard in the chapter INPUT/OUTPUT Statements: "3 The input/output statements are the BACKSPACE, CLOSE, ENDFILE, FLUSH, INQUIRE, OPEN, PRINT,
READ, REWIND, WAIT, and WRITE statements."

Comment: Understand, thanks. The open is a statement and iostat is a specifier not a formal argument. When the open procedure succeeds, the specifier decorated variable gets defined.

Comment: Given your use, @Gao, of "formal" a couple of times now I think I more understand your confusion.  If you come from a background language where assignment is an operator which may appear anywhere, it may look like there is assignment here.  There isn't: in Fortran assignment is a distinct statement only.  There once was a lot of discussion in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31885866/3157076) about _pointer assignment_ not being an operator.